# Updating Ruby Mac OS 10.6.8 Snow Leopard

Tags: ruby, macos, jekyll

I'm trying to install a more recent version of Ruby on Snow Leopard so I can install Jekyll. When trying to install any version of Jekyll I get an error saying that it requires liquid, which requires ruby v2+.

If I try upgrade via rbenv I get the following when trying all versions:

`error: failed to download ruby-2.1.1.tar.bz2`

`BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.6.8 using ruby-build 20181019)`

I've also installed Ruby manually from source but this isn't recognised by the system and I can't switch versions.
If i run `rbenv global` it only recognises the System version of Ruby.

When I try `brew upgrade ruby` I get the following error:

`ruby 2.5.3_1 already installed`

If I try link to the new version with brew I get the following error:

`brew link --force --overwrite ruby@2.5.3_1`

`Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby@2.5.3_1`

RVM doesn't install so I'm not sure what to do next. Below are the details of the packages I have installed.

Xcode 3.2.2 (I cant get an installer working for any higher versions of Xcode). The more recent versions hosted by Apple for Snow Leopard are corrupt when downloaded.

rbenv 1.1.1

brew 1.8.4

ruby 1.8.7 (System)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what actually fixed this but I ran the following commands after reading other posts and now have Jekyll 3.8.3 installed and ruby 2.5.3p105.

`sudo chown -R "$USER":admin /usr/local`

`export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

`brew link --overwrite ruby --force`

`gem install jekyll`

Answer (score 1):

You have (or had) a path issue. Before you did your follow up steps, if you had run `which ruby` you'd probably see it pointing to `/usr/bin/ruby` which is system ruby, not your homebrew ruby in `/usr/local/bin/ruby`.

You still need to, if you haven't already, add your export command to your `~/.bash_profile` file to ensure your `PATH` gets updated for every terminal window you open.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but a few people downvoted this response. If you can provide clarification I'd appreciate it. It's as common knowledge to everyone to update their shell profile as it is to export the path in the first place (e.g. not so common)